# UK tourist visa - Home Address

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

1) I am renting house currently . I am renting same apartment on monthly basis hence  I dont have long term signed agreement however I can share last 6 months Rental statement. It has appropriate information like my name, address and amount charged. The same amount deduction is showing up in bank statement.
2) Also, I have renters insurance document which is signed for 1 year.
3) Last 6 months Utility bills (like Electricity, Internet connection) are on my name with correct address which I can provide

Please suggest, above 3 documents will work for "Home Address" and "Evidence of assets"

Comment: UKVI won’t be interested in your insurance document or your utility bills. Your rental agreement may help prove ties to your country of residence https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: As @Traveller says, a rental agreement will show ties, especially if its been in effect for a longer duration, and act as a home address, but it will not however act as "evidence of assets" as a rental property is not *your* asset.

Comment: Which question are you trying to answer on the visa application?

Comment: Evidence for "home address"